# Subquery returned more than 1 value error while storing data in temporary table using split function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I tried to perform following operation. But it gives error "Subquery returned more than 1 value."

```
declare @filter varchar(100)='Moving,Idle,Stopped,Working'  
declare @filter2 varchar(100)='Init,suspend,Complete'    

create table #SPLITITEMS(value varchar(100),value1 varchar(100))
insert into #SPLITITEMS (value,value1)values((select val from dbo.split(@filter,',')),(select val from dbo.split(@filter2,',')))
```

so that I can perform

```
select * from table1 where column1 in (select value from #SPLITITEMS)
select * from table2 where column1 in (select value1 from #SPLITITEMS)
```

for better performance.

How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

```
declare @Q1 nvarchar(max)
declare @filter varchar(100)='Moving,Idle,Stopped,Working' 
declare @filter2 varchar(100)='Init,suspend,Complete'    

Set @filter = '''' + replace(@filter, ',', ''',''') + ''''
Set @filter2 = '''' + replace(@filter2, ',', ''',''') + ''''

Set @Q1 = 'select * from table1 where column1 in (' + @filter + ')'

Exec (@Q1)
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but i cant use it because the above given query is a small part of a large stored procedure.

Comment: We give you small solution cause you give small part....and how 'large' is your store proc?

Comment: the requirement is to insert the filter values in the form of column values in temporary table so that i can use it inside in clause like select * from table1 where column in (select value from #SPLITITEMS).Insert query works if the temporary table has only one column.But for multiple column it gives error.I cant use dynamic queries here.

Comment: base on your samples, the query should be ok...you'd better give us complete samples